# Discord.js: Creating a channel and doing that a webhook send something when it's created

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do a simple discord bot using discord.js that, when a channel is created and has a certain name, a webhook is created in that channel and sends something. I tried with different codes but I have no results (some time ago my code worked, now I don't know why it doesn't work).
Here's the code that I'm using (and worked time ago):

```js
bot.on('channelCreate', channel => {
    try {
        if (channel.name === 'test') {
            var webhook = channel.createWebhook('test webhook')
            webhook.send('Hello World')
        }} catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
})
```

The error that I'm having is this:

```js
TypeError: webhook.send is not a function
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.createWebhook` returns a promise, so you have to use `.then` or use async await, try this:

```js
bot.on('channelCreate', async (channel) => {
    try {
        if (channel.name === 'test') {
            var webhook = await channel.createWebhook('test webhook')
            webhook.send('Hello World')
        }} catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
})
```